# Perform view touch event when user touch children

Tags: java, android, view, touch-event

I created a custom view library and set up a touch event for it. I want when the user touches one of children in custom view, it gets the same touch events with the touched child.

How do I do this?!

Thanks.



Update Feb.16 / 2020

I add this code and it works fine:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    onTouchEvent(ev);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Without looking at your code, it would be too early to suggest, but you may intercept touches in [`onInterceptTouchEvent()`](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup) of `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Thanks. I used it and it works :)))

Comment: I don't know is it a correct way but I call `onTouchEvent(ev)` in `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and return false

Comment: Please update question with your code, that you've tried so far.